# is this Class diagram correct?what it mean

Tags: android, uml, class-diagram

I am starting a project creating a digital ordering using android. I have created a simple class diagram as you can see below. I just wanted some guidance on whether the relationships are correct for the entities?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This diagram is syntactically correct, as depepdencies are perfectly valid between two classes.

This diagrams shows that the class MainActivity **uses other two classes**, but *does not have tham as data members*. The typicall scenario modelled this way is that they are passed as parameters to a method of the class MainActivity or are instantiated within its method(s).

If this is what you wanted to show, the diagram is also semantically correct.